# Java method calls / line statics

Tags: java, profiling, code-coverage

I have different input data for a Java application.

Is there an easy way to see which methods and at best which code path
are "touched" when using a certain set of input data?

Best solution would give some statics on how much of the code paths are run
with that set of example data.

Comment: FYI, a search term that will help is "code coverage".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're using [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) for that. It's a code coverage tool for Eclipse IDE. If you don't want to use eclipse, you can just use [EMMA](http://emma.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 4):

The thing you're looking for is a **Code Coverage Tool**.  There are many available, and the major ones are listed here on Wikipedia: [Java Code Coverage Tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Code_Coverage_Tools).